# limpiar un panel desde un user control

Tags: c#

Tengo un user control en el cual tengo un botón llamado Cerrar, desde ahí deseo limpiar el panel que contiene ese User Control.

He probado hacer lo siguiente en el evento click del botón Cerrar que tengo dentro del User Control:

```
private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmPrincipal principal = new frmPrincipal();
        principal.panel1.Controls.Clear();

    }
```

No he tenido éxito al intentarlo, quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Quien contiene a quien, el USerControl tiene el Panel o el Panel contiene al user control

Comment: @DarielRamos El panel contiene el user control y el boton salir está en el user control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Con sender as Control lo que haces es obtener el objeto button al que le estas dando click
    //Necesitas 2 .Parent pk el primero te lleva al userControl y el segundo al Panel que lo contiene
    (sender as Control).Parent.Parent.Controls.Clear();
}
```

Si lo que deseas es ocultarlo intenta con esto

```
private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Con sender as Control lo que haces es obtener el objeto button al que le estas dando click
    //Necesitas 2 .Parent pk el primero te lleva al userControl y el segundo al Panel que lo contiene
    (sender as Control).Parent.Hide();
}
```

Y cuando lo quieras mostrar desde el formulario llamas a :

```
userControl1.Show();
```

Asumiendo que tu componente UserControl tenga ese nombre

Comment: Gracias Dariel, me funcionó pero una vez que me limpie el panel no puedo volver a invocarlo, como corrijo esa parte?

Comment: A que te refieres con volverlo a invocar si haces Controls.Clear ya ese usercontrol y boton no estaran

Comment: Claro, quiero decir que invoco el usercontrol desde el formulario principal, y una vez lo invoque y lo cierre no puedo volver a invocarlo.

Comment: alguna ayuda de como corregir esta situación?

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es ocultarlo y si kieres invocarlo de nuevo lo muestras

Comment: Edite la respuesta mira ver si te sirve con esos datos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pude resolver gracias a su ayuda.

Comment: No hay de que para eso estamos en esta comunidad ;P